# Extract username from link?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to extract usernames from a profile link.

The profile link example: https://username.site.com

I don't  know if it has http, https, ends in a slash, and it could be a lot of things. It could have `/photo/tkf39vk3` or anything. Is there any 1 solid regex that will help with this? Other questions don't help.

What have I tried so far?

```
((?:[^.](?<!www))+)\.site\.com
```

It gets everything but includes the http or https?

Comment: This would be much easier if you used the `Uri` class

Comment: Solving your problems with regexes is often like solving them with liquor, but at least with liquor you make friends.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." -Jamie Zawinski

Comment: I can use the Uri class, simply parse the string to Uri, convert it, and parse back to string. @maccettura

Comment: @user692959239 parse into a URI, check the DnsSafeHost property, then you can split on `'.'` and take the 0 index

Comment: @BrootsWaymb The ones who quote jwz have three problems. That's when you cut your losses and turn to liquor.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - You can say what you want about those quotes, but that one definitely flies through my head and makes me at second guess resorting to regex at the very least. No need for liquor. It's not about cutting regex out completely, but not jumping to it as a first resort.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb In all seriousness, regexes can be invaluable when used responsibly and in moderation.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach it is by leveraging the [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`UriBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) classes:

```
string[] inputArray = new[] 
{
    "https://username1.site.com",
    "https://username2.site.com/photo/asdasd",
    "https://username.site.com/photo/tkf39vk3",
    "http://username3.site.com/photo/tkf39vk3",
    "username4.site.com/photo/tkf39vk3"
};

foreach(string i in inputArray)
{
    //Parses into Uri object, using UriBuilder to accommodate lack of http/https    
    Uri uri = new UriBuilder(i).Uri;

    //Splits on '.' and grabs the first item    
    Console.WriteLine(uri.DnsSafeHost.Split('.')[0]);
}
```

This would output:

> username1
>
> username2
>
> username
>
> username3
>
> username4

Of course you have to have a reasonable input expectation with my solution (which you have to do with regex also), but you could easily make it more robust with some tweaking.  I just wanted to show the simplest solution.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GS2ruI)

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this, but likely not the best thing would be to split it on `//` and then again on `.`

```
string profileLink = "https://username.site.com";

var list = profileLink.Split(new string[] { @"//" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var result = list[1].Split('.');
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```

Comment: I took that to mean they didnt know if it was http or https.. if it means it could be neither of those, then this solution wouldnt work